# Can Window Service be used to have business Logic

Tags: rest, rabbitmq, windows-services, business-logic

There is requirement in project and the windows service needs to be used as subscriber of RabbitMQ (message broker).

Once the event has created, this listener windows service get the event and process the event, while processing, there are some important business logics needs to be incorporated and the data needs to be stored into SQL server DB.

From my perspective, windows service can be just a trigger of any business logic. Like once it subscribed to an event, if any event comes, read the event details and perform the business logic using any of the REST (HTTP based) service.

Please provide your suggestions, it would be more helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I least I didn't understand your question or the title.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Windows application using c# or you can use NUGET rabbitmq client to consume message and save in dB.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/RabbitMQ.Client